# Запуск нескольких (разных) серверов python Flask

Tags: python, flask

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть практическая задача, связанна с удаленным запуском нескольких серверов Flask на одном хосте с различными портами.
Как правильно оформить процедуру их параллельного запуска?

Comment: Настроить апач, mod_wsgi и запускать апач. Разные сервера - разные вирутальные хосты апача.

Answer (score 2):

Я использую для управлениями несколькими веб приложениями Flask (3 приложения) на сервере с os debian 7.9 -

```
supervisor
```

в качестве WSGI сервера -

```
gunicorn
```

доступ к 2 приложениям осуществляю через порт указанный в соответствующих конфигурационных файлах supervisor -а, одно приложение работает в связке с nginx.

Возможно в новых версиях os linux не используют supervisor в пользу systemd но на описанный мной случай полно инструкций по настройке.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! А напрямую из одного python-скрипта это сделать нельзя?

Comment: если Вы имеете ввиду запуск 2 серверов для разработки с помощью app.run() в одном файле - то нельзя.

Comment: но можно без всяких настроек запустить 2 приложения через ssh с помощью screen. 

screen app1.py,  ctrl + D (для отсоединения от консоли) и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Указываем явно сам порт . У нас на проекте так 12 фласков запущено

```
HOST_PORT="5000"
app = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=HOST_PORT)
```